# I am not able to set my class into a promise on Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

when I've executed the function getLocalPosition() and inside I try to set my variable of class Position, I receive the next error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLat' of null
    at VM11086 main.js:52673
    at t.invoke (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (VM11086 main.js:34675)
    at t.invoke (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at e.run (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at VM11035 polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM11086 main.js:34666)
    at t.invokeTask (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at e.runTask (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
VM11086 main.js:52685 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLon' of null
    at VM11086 main.js:52681
    at t.invoke (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (VM11086 main.js:34675)
    at t.invoke (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at e.run (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at VM11035 polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (VM11086 main.js:34666)
    at t.invokeTask (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
    at e.runTask (VM11035 polyfills.js:3)
```

But if I set my class in the constructor is working fine.

here is my .ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Position } from './clases';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  private position = new Position();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
    this.position.setLat(1234311);
    console.log(this.position);
    // Or to get a key/value pair
    this.storage.get('position').then((val) => {
      this.position = val;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  getLocalPosition() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp => {

      try {
        this.position.setLat(resp.coords.latitude);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
          console.log(e);

        }
      }
      try {
        this.position.setLon(resp.coords.longitude);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TypeError) {
          console.log(e);

        }
      }

      //this.storage.set('position', this.position);
    }))
  }


}
```

and here my class

```js
export class Position {
    private lat: number;
    private lon: number;

    constructor(lat: number = 0, lon: number = 0) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;

    }
    setLat(lat: number) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    setLon(lon: number) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
    getLat() {
        return this.lat;
    }
    getLon() {
        return this.lon;
    }

    getPosition() {
        let position = {
            lat: this.lat,
            lon: this.lon
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

thanks for your time

Comment: It may be a typo in your OP but please try by changing this line `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp => {` to `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {` (closing the parenthesis after the `resp`). Please also notice that you'll need to remove a closing parenthesis at the end of the `then` method.

Comment: I fixed that but the issue still persist.

Comment: When/where are you calling the `getLocalPosition` method?

Comment: when I press a button in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this line

```
this.storage.get('position').then((val) => {
  this.position = val;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I set this.position with val and after it's impossible to access to the method setLat because it doesn't exists.